# Need to build GUI with no conditional compilation

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, cmake, wxwidgets

recently i have been searching on what should i use to build an application in C++ with GUI and found wxWidgets and QT were mostly used lately , but ive read that QT has the chance to dominate in the near future thus it was preferred by many i have never used it but i was wondering why is it becoming so popular. however, i don't know if it can meet my requirements.

The goal is to make sure we have software that runs on both Windows and Linux without complicated configuration (like installing MinGW just to run my application), and compiles on both without any conditional compilation. i have to stick with the “no conditional compilation” rule;

i want to know if CMake can take care of all that whether i used wxWidgets or QT.

Comment: what do you understand by "no conditional compilation"? No `#ifdef` inside your code or no conditional selection of files inside your Cmake?

Comment: CMake + Qt will satisfy your conditions just fine.

Comment: wxWidgets doesn't need additional software to run, because it is implemented on any platform using native API calls for this platform. Regarding "no conditional compilation" - you really need to explain what you mean.

Comment: no conditional compilation meant to make sure the software runs in linux and windows without the need of installing other complicated things i just mentioned the objective twice to emphasize on what i needed. i just thought that QT could be complicated but it seems that it would work fine and its worth using

Thanks all

Comment: To build software using Qt, you need to have a full Qt developer package installed. Once you do, the building takes literally two commands: `qmake` followed by `make`. It doesn't get much simpler than that. You don't even need to use cmake to start with. `qmake` is part of Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer the situation for CMake and Qt. If you are using Qt together with CMake, you can build executables which are working for Windows and Linux without changing a line of code, or the need to have conditional code.

This is also the reason why Qt got this dominant. It simply saves a lot of time, because you have to write all your code only once, and just need to compile the same source on different platforms.

Also the code stays very clean, because you don't need any "macro magic" to build different code between Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i just needed to know if QT was flexible to use and it seems that it is so i will try using it now

the thing is my partner sometimes codes on his linux platform and if using QT means that we can code on both windows and linux easily without changing the code then that sounds great!

Comment: This should be the case. The only thing which you have to care is: A) the Qt library itself. Both, on Windows and Linux you have to build the library with the same options and modules. And B) of course to make sure your code is portable, you must not use any platform specific APIs (e.g. Windows APIs). For almost everything, there is a Qt API you should use instead of platform specific APIs. Hence the Qt documentation is absolutely great, so you will find there everything you need.

Answer (score -1):

For my projects I tend to use wxWidgets (where I need a GUI) on both Linux and Windows. For windows I use [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) as toolchain with wxWidgets compiled statically (or any other library that I use).

So when I deliver a new release for the windows platform I don't need to worry about dependencies for the end-user, since that is being statically linked in the executable. Sure you can do the same with dynamic linking, but it's less of a pain to just have everything linked into the application. The Windows release is normally produced through Code::Blocks but could as easily be done through a makefile on Windows as well (using mingw-w64).

On Linux I normally just deliver the source code on a new release. On Linux i use a simple makefile.

Comment: OP asks if CMake can handle different configurations for different platforms for either Qt or wxWidgets. Also, it seems as OP doesn't like to install another compiler (mingw) for the project. Maybe you could extend this answer in those directions. As it is, it is more an opinion than an answer.